# How to implement Spinner properly

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a problem with a **Spinner** inside an AlertDialog. The spinner text doesn't wrap automatically. I tried to use:

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

but Android Studio says that it is redundant.

Also I have tried: `spinnerMode="dialog"` but nothing.

How can I solve this? This is a part of my code:

```
ArrayList<String> attivita_spinner = new ArrayList<>();
attivita_spinner.add("Cammina occasionalmente.");
attivita_spinner.add("In poltrona. Abilità a camminare severamente limitata o inesistente. Non sostiene il proprio peso e/o deve essere assistito per raggiungere la poltrona o la sedia a rotelle.");
attivita_spinner.add("Allettato. Confinato a letto.");

final Spinner attivita = new Spinner(getContext());
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter_attivita = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, attivita_spinner);
attivita.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter_attivita);
```

Comment: you need to customize your spinner layout

Answer (score 0):

To use custom layout and perfectly match your spinner items to your layout you should make your own item layout.

For that you'll need an adapter too.

Here is a nice tutorial I've actually followed a long time ago. [tutorial link](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-spinner-dropdown-example/)

Basically what the adapter does is to 'adapt' your own item layout (which your'e going to make) to your spinner.